# ion-slide-box two way binding not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ion-slide-box

I am having problem with ion-slide-box implementation

[Link to sample not working](http://jsbin.com/zitohozovi/embed?html,js,console,output)

I want to achieve two way binding as below

[Two way binding with out ionic slidebox](http://jsbin.com/dunomowira/embed?html,js,console,output)

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Still waiting for solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. There might better way to fix it but i can only think of this at the moment

I have to modify ion-slide-box directive a bit

Here is my code:

**Ionic bundle.js  (Create two way Binding here)**

```
IonicModule.directive('ionSlideBox', [........,
   function(...){
       return{
         scope:{
          counter: "=",
          ...... 
        },
        controller: [.....,function(){
         _this.getCounter = function(){   
            return $scope.counter;   
          }

         _this.setCounter = function(val){
             scope.counter = val;
             $scope.$broadcast( "IncrementValue" );
          }
        }]
   }
}
```

**Directive.js**

```
directive('updateCounter', function(){
return{
    restrict : 'A',
    scope : false,
    require : '^ionSlideBox',
    link : function(scope,element, attrs,ctrl){
        $(element).click(function(){
            scope.counter = ctrl.getCounter();
            scope.counter--;
            ctrl.setCounter(scope.counter);
        })
    }
}})
```

**ViewController.js**

```
$scope.$on(
  "IncrementValue",
  function handleIncrementValue() {
        $scope.counter++;
  }
);
$scope.triggerEvent = function() {
  $scope.$broadcast( "IncrementValue" );
};
```

**View.html**

```
 <ion-slide-box counter="counter">
     <ion-slide>
       <button ng-click="trigger()">Increment box</button>
       <button update-counter>Decrement box</button>
     </ion-slide>
 </ion-slide-box>
```

If there is better way please let me know

Thanks